# How do I do this if statement?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to learn code from scratch and am doing the pre course work for lambda and I have hit a hard brick wall lol. I'm a bit older (36) and have no college education and wanted to pursue this for a while but always figured I wasn't smart enough but here I am attempting it. I am on the section of logical operators and if/else statements. I sort of get the concept but I think I am just not following how they word certain questions. I have been on the following question for about three hours and am ready to put my head thru the computer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
  let lovesPizza;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: typeOfPizza
  // You are also given another variable called: lovesPizza;
  // Using an if/else statement assign lovesPizza to true if typeOfPizza is 'pepperoni', assign it to false if it is 'olives'
```

Comment: Hi, what specifically are you stuck on with this question (are you finding it hard to understand the question or finding it difficult to write a solution, etc...)? Have you tried anything so far that you think would work?

Comment: You've got the right idea. When you don't put quotes around a word in JS, JS will think it is a variable which you have defined somewhere within your code. To tell JS that pepperoni is a word (ie a _string_), you'll need to put quotes around pepperoni like so `"pepperoni"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone starts at the beginning. Good on you for spending the time to learn. The people who are downvoting are probably doing so because you're supposed to show what you've tried so far in your post. When you get the chance, please do so. But here's the code before this question gets too many downvotes to be answered. I hope it helps. I trust you'll take the time to study it and learn from it. If you have questions about it, leave a comment.

```
function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
    let lovesPizza;

    if(typeOfPizza == 'pepperoni'){
        lovesPizza = true;
    }
    else if(typeOfPizza == 'olives'){
        lovesPizza = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I will study this and is extremely helpful. I will hopfeully come back to this post in a year and laugh at myself. Have a great night!

Comment: @scottj614 Forget about a year, you will come back in a week and have a laugh haha As Aaron stated, you have to start somewhere. Do not worry about your age, education level, or if you are smart enough, you will be fine. Have fun and dive in.